# how do I get a value into a webdriver statement?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

trying to get the value of t into this webdriver statement.

I've tried:

```
t = 2
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-{t})").format(t)

driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-{t})")
```

what I want is:

```
driver.driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-2)")
```

Comment: You want to interpolate?  For example (in ruby): `"some_string_#{t}"`.  You should indicate your language of choice in order to get accurate answers.

Comment: For that specific script, you might prefer `driver.navigate.back` (ruby) or `driver.navigate().back()` (python).

Comment: So you have a problem with language syntax (and nothing to do with Selenium), but you did not specify **which** language.

Answer (score 0):

using `format`, you can do:

```
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-{})".format(t))
```